# Cpu hot resize on windows on XEN

Tags: windows, resize, cpu, xen

I have a XEN Hypervisor with following config for Windows Virtual Machine

```
vcpu_avail = "1" #(number of VCPUs to boot the system with)

vcpus = "4" #(maximum number of VCPUs (total) that can be hot added later)
```

But when windows loaded and i check the number of CPUs which windows uses - i see all 4 CPU.
I tried fix it by command "bcdedit /set numproc 1", reboot VM - all works fine, windows uses 1 CPU.

Next question - i try to make hot resize for this Windows VM:

```
xm vcpu-set vm_name 2
```

then go to my windows - nothing changed, it still use 1 cpu and sometimes i see windows popup with error like this - "MY_CPU_DESCRIPTION device is not removable and cannot be ejected or unplugged"

Can anybody help me? Maybe special windows driver needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add vcpus at run time , you would like to use "xm vcpu-add   ".
Doing hot add of vcpus does not work in all the scenarios (These are bugs in fact that are yet to be fixed as per my knowledge)